# inserting and viewing fractions using strings in C

Tags: c, string, sorting, fractions

For my program I am trying to ask the user to insert a fraction then if they hit option 2 it will display those fractions. So far I figured out how to ask the user for a number and it stores that number, how ever I need the code to ask to enter a numerator then when I hit enter I would enter the denominator. I believe my code to view the numbers is written correctly however I need it to display fractions, which is what I am having difficulty with.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;

    while (num == 0) {
        int num1;

        printf("\nPress 1 to enter a the fraction\n");
        printf("Press 2 view the fractions\n");

        scanf("%d", &num1);

        int num[100][500];
        int n[100];

        if (num1 == 1)
        {
            printf("Enter the numerator followed by the denominator\n");
            scanf("%s", n);
            strcpy(num[i], n);
            i++;
        }

        if (num1 == 2)
        {
            printf("\n-----------------------------");
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                printf("\n%s\n", &num[j]);
            }
            printf("\n\n-----------------------------");
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", n);`? `n` is an int, and should be a POINTER to an int, and since you're scanning for a string (`%s`), it makes no sense whatsoever to store that string in a single int.

Comment: Save time.  `int n[100]; ... scanf("%s", n);` should generate a compiler warning.  Insure all compiler warnings are enabled.

Comment: so how would i ask for the fraction?